# Selenium Web Driver - How to narrow down my search using xpath? //* is not sufficient

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

Firstly thanks for your time.

I am trying to use selenium to find an entry in a listbox of my web app

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='" + title + "']")).click();
```

How would I go about modifying my code to stop searching for everything and search for the following: (myXpath output on my Listbox from firebug/firepath)

```
<div id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey_upSurveysList">
```

Thanks again, could you also explain as best as possible your answer, I'm trying to learn this as I will need it a lot going forward

```html
<div id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey_upSurveysList">
Displaying 1-10 of 47 Records
<div class="ListBox">
<div class="divListItem">
<a id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey_lvSurveys_ctrl0_ctl00_btnApplicationID" class="manCensoredName" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey$lvSurveys$ctrl0$ctl00$btnApplicationID','')">11</a>
</div>
<div class="divListItem">
<div class="divListItem">
<div class="divListItem">
<div class="divListItem">
<div class="divListItem">
<div class="divListItem">
<div class="divListItem">
<div class="divListItem">
<div class="divListItem">
```

Comment: can you add listbox html ?

Comment: Edited with some more information, thanks

Comment: do you wan to count total no. of list..

Comment: I just want to select an entry in the listbox which I can then delete, I have a param'd function which takes title, searches for it & removes it, but im currently searching the entire page for the title rather than just the listbox

Comment: what is item name for this? I mean between this : <div class="divListItem"></div>

Comment: You mean something like this `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey_upSurveysList']");`?

Comment: you can do like `driver.findElement(by.id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey_lvSurveys_ctrl0_ctl00_btnApplicationID");` , it will find first item from list.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro how do I go about adding my contains text to the end of that?

*[text()='" + title + "']")).click(); for example, trying on my end but can't seem to get it right

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_Main‌​ContentPlaceHolderSurvey_upSurveysList']//*[text()='" + title + "']");` Like this?

Comment: Please update the HTML to be more complete. Put some example text in there in the format you find it in so we can see a complete example of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write that one like:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'upSurveysList')].click();`

No need to write the entire id;

Using the "contains" method of selecting xpaths, you can take any partial text out of the div to match it (as long as that text doesn't appear elsewhere in the html, but in your case, I don't think it would).

I shy away from using `//*` at all times, for it searches through absolutely everything. Depending on the size of your web application, if you know you're accessing a `div` or a `canvas` or an `img`, you can reduce your test times as well as increase xpath accuracy and maintainability.

Also, I know personally, my webapplication is extremely finicky, and the use of `Actions` and `WebElement` is the only way to click on the majority of my buttons.

For example:

```
WebElement mybutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'upSurveysList')].click();
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(mybutton).build().perform();
mybutton.click();
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

C# exemple to click on link:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey_upSurveysList")).Click();
```

For doing it in XPath:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolderSurvey_upSurveysList']")).Click();
```